# How can I prevent a user from logging in from more than one computer or browser?

Tags: users

In the Drupal 7 web site I am developing, I have a requirement that will not allow a user to login from multiple computers or different browser (IE and FireFox) on the same computer.  It looks like the [Session limit](http://drupal.org/project/session_limit) module used to handle this, but I don't see where it is even under development for Drupal 7.  Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 6):

If you look into the modules issue queue, you would see that there is already a very active port underway. You could help to get it to a solid release by testing it out.

See [Issue #1047132: Session Limit version for D7](http://drupal.org/node/1047132)

Comment: Yes, I saw that and am happy to test out (and will) but I can't push that code to our client's production site when it seems to be very much under development.

Comment: In your question, you stated "...I don't see where it is even under development for Drupal 7...". I am just pointing it out that it is. I think your going to have to wait as any other module that implements this is either abandoned and/or doesn't even have a D6 version. but someone else can chime in if they know of another.

Comment: @John Lullabot use this in conjonction with [ejector seat](https://github.com/Lullabot/ejectorseat) for their [Videola platform](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/introducing-videola).